# Submenus is not adding in Report parent menu in magento admin

Tags: magento-1.9, module, submenu

In am trying to add a custom submenu in **Reports->Products->Stock Status** as shown in below image--

[image]

Here is my **adminhtml.xml** file--

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
      <report>
         <children>
            <products>
                <children>
                   <stockstatus translate="title" module="stockstatus">
                     <title>Stock Status</title>
                     <action</action>
                     <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                   </stockstatus>
                </children>
            </products>
         </children>
      </report>
    </menu>

    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
              <children>
                    <report>
                        <children>
                           <products>
                              <children>
                                <stockstatus>
                                   <title>Stock Status</title>
                                </stockstatus>
                              </children>
                           </products>
                        </children>
                    </report>
               </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

What is wrong there ? I am not getting submenus there.

Comment: insetd of stockstats you use submenu

Comment: <submenu translate="title" module="stockstatus">
                     <title>Stock Status</title>
                     <action</action>
                     <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                   </submenu >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need edit menu tag( miss `>` in `<action>`):

```
<menu>
  <report>
     <children>
        <products>
            <children>
               <stockstatus>
                 <title>Stock Status</title>
                 <action></action>
                 <sort_order>10</sort_order>
               </stockstatus>
            </children>
        </products>
     </children>
  </report>
</menu>
```